# How to subtract from a MySQL field with a minimum result of zero?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a query similar to this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET count = count - 2
```

The number two is variable. The field ***count*** may never be less than zero.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET count = GREATEST(0, count - 2);
```

Comment: I prefer this. It strikes me as more readable and has less points of failure particularly given that 2 is a variable.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `case` expression:

```
UPDATE mytable SET count = case when count >= 2 then count - 2 else 0 end
```

ANSI SQL compliant, i.e. it will execute with basically any dbms product!